# When should I use threads within tasks? - FreeRTOS

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, multitasking, freertos

I'm about to develop an FreeRTOS based embedded system that will run on a ESP32 chip. According to the [API Reference](https://esp-idf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-reference/system/index.html) I can create tasks and as well as pthreads.

Is there any rule of thumb that tells me if I should implement a functionality as a task or as thread? 
For example: If I'd like to handle three peripherals paralelly (just simple reading, so: short code, low performace, nearly any memory needed), I should create a new task or a new thread?

Comment: 'simple' and 'reading' are not often seen in the same sentence when discussing I/O in an RTOS environment.  Interrupts, DMA and kenel signaling are usually required to perform I/O in any kind of efficient, RTOS-friendly manner:(

Answer (score 2):

FreeRTOS have tasks. pthread is suggested as a wrapper to task for portability and compatability with POSIX systems and code.

Anyway, FreeRTOS do not have memory seperation, virtualization and remapping on context switch between tasks, so all it's tasks are what POSIX would call threads.